# Powers of logarithm question

Tags: logarithms

I have got a question about formal simple mathematics are these expressions equivalent?

$$ \log^{n} (x/a) $$

and  $$ \log^{n} (x) -\log^{n} (a) $$

I know is a dumb question and they are equal only when $ x= a$ but need some help

Comment: The first expression is $(\log x - \log a )^n$.

Comment: Might be useful if you actually *asked* a question. Or maybe do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

they are not equivalent, and you can see it directly for $n=2$ written as product.
you have $=(\log(x)-\log(a))^2$

Answer (score 0):

Nope. They are not equal. Raised to the power of n in both expressions make the quotient rule not working.